# Chrome returns 204 No Content

Tags: google-chrome

When I try to open certain urls using Chrome, I often get a message like <sub>(loosely translated)</sub>:

> Oops! Google Chrome cannot resolve {url}.
>   Try loading: {url}

This happens on multiple devices - laptops and smartphones using Chrome. Internet explorer seems to handle these requests just fine. Note that this does not happen *all the time*. Also, I am not sure this happens outside our own local network. Loading these pages from a mobile network (3G) using a phone seems to work just fine.

I've inspected the requests using Wireshark, with the following results. These were calls to the Dutch news site [nu.nl](http://www.nu.nl):

**Failed using Chrome:**

```
GET /csi?v=3&s=linkdoctor&action=opt&it=wtsrt_.0,tbsd_.23,tbnd_.0&tbsrt=23&tran=15&e=&rt=ol.25 HTTP/1.1
Host: csi.gstatic.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,nl;q=0.6

HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: private, no-cache
Expires: Wed, 17 Sep 1975 21:32:10 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Last-Modified: Wed, 21 Jan 2004 19:51:30 GMT
Content-Type: image/gif
Date: Mon, 14 Jul 2014 08:40:22 GMT
Server: Golfe2
Content-Length: 0
Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic
```

**Success using IE:**

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: nu.nl
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: __vrf=1405327477410LetsGPYVrmhz4el6d3v0eeLUrM0gakpP; __utma=1.111549304.1405327477.1405327477.1405327477.1; __utmb=1.2.10.1405327477; __utmc=1; __utmz=1.1405327477.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); SanomaWebSession=v3e4czhh9r; SanomaWeb=twzfjscb8v; __gads=ID=512afd3149fbc2e6:T=1405327481:S=ALNI_MZJb6lep2HsOLr-hXR6vjo1efQ-2w; __vrl=; __vry=0; __vru=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nu.nl%2F; __vrid=118; __vrm=590_-49_650

HTTP/1.1 301 MOVED PERMANENTLY
Location: http://www.nu.nl/
Via: sanin009.noa
```

I'm using the following Chrome versions:

- Windows 8.1 Pro: 35.0.1916.153 m
- Android 4.4.4: 36.0.1985.65

What is happening here?

---

The first time there was no 'more' button, now there is. 
The error code is:

> Error code: ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED

I'm suspecting it's something in the router, as this happens on multiple devices (in the local network). It is a TP-Link TL-WDR4300. It has the latest firmware installed, and I've tried a factory reset.
When this problem occurs, it does so only for a few sites, other sites load fine.
Pinging the problematic url works fine as well.

Comment: The request from Chrome is associated to the omnibar. It is only losely related to your actual browsing. You said Chrome displays an error message. Is there a “More” button? If so, please click it and update your question with the error code displayed. It would be something like `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED` suggests your DNS queries are failing sporadically. I would try a few things:

- Measure your packet loss. DNS uses UDP for small requests and UDP is sensitive to lost packages. You can use [PingTest.net](http://pingtest.net) to measure this.
- Change your DNS server. Maybe you are using a local one that is having problems, which explains why the errors happen on different devices on the same network. I personally like Google's DNS servers, available at `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`. [Here's a guide](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using?csw=1) on how to setup it on different systems.
- [Flush your DNS cache](http://www.wikihow.com/Flush-DNS) to ensure all entries are correct.

None of these explain why the error is exclusive to Chrome, but without knowing exactly how they handle their requests it's hard to know. Maybe Chrome gives up on the first try to resolve the domain, for example, while IE uses a number of retries to mask the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. PingTest shows 0% packet loss. I have changed the DNS servers to the ones you provided in the router. The problem is gone for now, but as said before, it occurs at random times. I will keep you updated!

Comment: The problem did not occur anymore in the last two days. Thanks!